# kubernetes apiserver "the server could not find the requested resource"

Tags: atomic, kubernetes

So I am hesitant to ask as a newbie but I have hit a wall.  I am following:

http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/gettingstarted/

Using fedora atomic host 22 latest.

I had trouble getting the system up with some of the port settings and with the api string.  I was able to get all my services running on the master and my three minions.  Kubelet and kube-proxy are failing to connect to the apiserver.  I am able to reach the server from curl but the api paths return:

http://cas-vm-atomic-m:8080/api/v1beta3

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1beta3",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server could not find the requested resource",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {},
  "code": 404
}

KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="--admission_control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ResourceQuota"
```

I have turned up the logging.  I have tried a variety of setting for KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL.  I think my problem is on the master and with the apiserver being up but not serving working correctly.  kubectl does return my three nodes and services and endpoints.  But the nodes stay in NotReady status.  The node are attempting to move out of NotReady but can't reach the apiserver to do so.

I am kinda of bummed that the newbie getting started howto has been so difficult.  Though I guess educational.  I have the logging set to 3 but now I mostly see the kube-proxy requests failing with 404 errors.  Any ideas?

If this is the wrong place for this please let me know.

Comment: Welcome Chris. Can you please pay attention to fomatting in future. If your question is not readable then fewer people will read it. I've formatted it for you so you can see how.

Answer (score 1):

That guide probably needs to be updated, given that the kubernetes v1beta3 api was deprecated in [July](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/11737). I suspect you're running a recent build of the apiserver (which supports only the v1 api), but older builds of kube-proxy/kubelet.

I'd recommend following one of the getting started guides from [kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/README.html), as those are pretty stable and have dedicated maintainers. e.g. the [flannel on fedora](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/flannel_multi_node_cluster.html) guide sounds pretty close to what you're setting up and having trouble with.

Comment: Well I am running whatever comes on the current fedora atomic host image.  So I guess if that is broken it is time to go back to something else.  It seems like having this howto listed and not work is kind of a bad idea.  I would be happy to help fix it but I don't feel like I know enough to even get it working.  So is this a bug then with the current atomic fedora image?